# Open socket and send packets in PHP through SOCKS5

Tags: php, sockets, curl, proxy, tunnel

Ive currently made a simple PHP script that opens a socket and sends some TCP data to server. I run this PHP script on my machine so my IP shows in the server. I would like to tunnel this PHP script through a SOCKS5 proxy. Ive tried opening a SOCKS5 with cURL in the PHP script but it still showed my real IP in the server. Is there a specific way to do this process? To tunnel a single PHP script that sends some TCP packets and make it go through my SOCKS5 proxy?

Comment: Are you sure your proxy is anonymous?

Comment: It is anonymous for sure! Why? :)